# GIT_EDITOR set to Notepad++ but still getting Vi

Tags: git, editor

If I type "git var GIT_EDITOR" I get
"c:\program files\notepad++\notepad++.exe"
(I have it set in the system environment variable screen
and that's where notepad++.exe is located).

But if I type something like "git log  -p HEAD..FETCH_HEAD" I get vi. Also in other places like "git commit" without -m

How do I get Notepad++ to run instead of vi?
git version 2.37.1.windows.1

Comment: (As a sidenote, the editor is not supposed to be launched upon `git log` (+options), regardless of which editor is configured. With `git commit`, yes.)

Comment: You probably aren't getting vi, you're probably getting `less` here (which deliberately behaves slightly similar to vi). That's your *pager*, from `git var GIT_PAGER`. Configure `core.pager` or set environment variable `GIT_PAGER` to some other pager you like better, if you have one you like better. (I can't explain the `git commit` behavior though: if `git var GIT_EDITOR` says notepad++ you should be getting notepad++, or a complaint that it can't be run.)

Comment: I think you're right about less not vi.

However, when I do a 'git commit' now I get
hint: Waiting for your editor to close the file... C:\program files\Notepad++\Notepad++.exe: C:program: command not found
error: There was a problem with the editor 'C:\program files\Notepad++\Notepad++.exe'.
Please supply the message using either -m or -F option.  

[But Notepad++ is not running.]

Comment: @PaulKinzelman have you tried running `git config --global core.editor "'C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe' -multiInst -notabbar -nosession -noPlugin"`

NOTE: if it's Windows 32-bit, the file path will vary.  Also note that this will globally set your editor. If you'd prefer to set it per-repository, you can use `--local` instead of `--global`.
I tested it on Windows 10 in Git bash version `2.21.0.windows.1` and it works, both with and without the additional arguments after Notepad++.exe.

Comment: I tried that git config string and now 'commit -m' which should pull up the editor now says  "error: switch 'm' requires a value" and no editor at all.